# Преимущества MongoDB, SQLite, NoSQL сравнительно с MySQL

Tags: mongodb, база-данных, sqlite, nosql, mysql

Всем привет. Я раньше работал только с базой данной MySQL. Сейчас также начал интересоваться такими базами данных как MongoDB, SQLite, NoSQL. Какие у них преимущества перед БД MySQL? Какую базу данных, из перечисленных выше, лучше использовать и под какие задачи? Прощу меня сильно не пинать, только сегодня начал изучать этот вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос ни о чем. @Dex вам "тоненько" намекает об этом в своем ответе =)

Ну а вам, как понимаю лично пофиг на суть вопроса, раз принят ответ, где особо ничего "супер полезного" не указано.

---
**P.S** @Dex, лично к вам никаких претензий не имею, уж не подумайте =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все же начну с небольшого пинка, NoSQL - это целый класс, в который, кстати, входит MongoDB.

MySQL это не просто [БД](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/База_данных), впрочем, как и все остальное, - это СУБД, причем реляционная.

Начните, пожалуй, с этого, разберитесь с [типами](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Система_управления_базами_данных) СУБД. Затем загляние в [noSQL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

И после этого часть ваших вопросов отпадет сама собой. Особенно в отношении [MongoDB](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) и [SQLite](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sqlite). Вы поймете, где и почему их удобно было бы использовать.

---

Вроде P.S.

NoSQL вообще очень интересная и весьма пропагандируемая тема на сегодняшний день, в первую очередь хотя бы потому, что начинается все с множественных полей, плавно перетекает в [Data Mining](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining), и у меня закончилось на [MapReduce](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за ссылки, уже читаю!

Answer (score 7):

NoSQL - это вообще не база, а класс хранилищ данных, клоторые не относятся к традиционным SQL базам данных. Так, что из предложенных тобой вариантов остается только два: SQLite и MongoDb.

SQLite - это встраиваемое SQL решение, основанное на файлах. Если на пальцах - это апи доступа к данным, которые хранятся в локальных файлах посредством SQL синтаксиса, т.е. мало чем отличается от классических fread/fwrite и имеет те же недостатки, что и хранение данных на файлах.

ну что, теперь остается MongoDb - это система хранения данных, основанная на принципе хранении документов в BSON(Binary JSON) формате. 
Достоинства:

- имеет распределенный доступ к данным, расположенных на нескольких серверах
- возможно параллельное извлечение данных MapReduce
- более быстрое извлечение простых структур данных
- может хранить неструктурную информацию

Недостатки:

- менее чем более стабильна, не рекомендовано использовать в биллинге
- требовательна к ресурсам - память и место на диске
- Лочится вся коллекция, если используется внутренние функции которые работают с данными данной коллекции (аналог хранимых процедур). аналог творится то, что и с MyISAM.
- проблемы с решардингом

что использовать во многом зависит от задачи и имеющихся для ее решения ресурсов:
где-то лучше использовать MongoDb, где-то redis, где-то Reak или Cassandra.

А для этого надо познакомиться с ними со всеми поближе... Почитать блоги, развернуть на дев сервере, покрутить настройки и прочие ручечки.
Не реализовав на них ни одного проекта, нельзя говорить о достоинствах и недостатках.

В одном реализованном мною проекте, при использовании MongoDB, запихнулии ее на виртуалку, дали 1Гб и 2 ядра с возможностью перспективы роста проекта... Но, набрав какое-то кол-во пользователей, где-то более миллиона, MongoDb начала притормаживать из-за нехватки ресурсов... А выделенного сервера для нее так и не выдали, сказав, что проект сделан неправильно и тормозит... так что надо осознавать риски связанные с железом и используемым на нем софтом